# Python import library from tar.gz?

Tags: python, path, tar, egg

I am working on a box which I don't have root access. However, there is a folder /share which would be accessed for everyone to read and write.

I want to figure out a way to put python libraries so that everyone could access and use them.

I figured out that I can put the egg file in the /share/pythonLib folder and in the python script.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/share/pythonLib/foo.egg")
import foo
```

and it would work for everyone, however, I am not sure every library has egg version. For example, I am trying to install [BeautifulSoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) , however, there is only tar.gz file and I am not sure if it would be possible to convert to egg and ..etc.

OR! I am wrong right at the BEGINNING, and there are indeed some pythonic magics like below:

```
magicadd /share/pythonLib/foo.tar.gz
import foo
```

Comment: How about install the package to the shared directory? If you are using pip, try `pip install -t /share/pythonLib BeautifulSoup4`.

Comment: OSError:[Errno13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python..../__init__.pyc'  Seems like it still trying to touch some file that it should not touch

Comment: It seems like beautifulsoup is already installed globally in your system. pip tries to delete old installation.

Comment: foo.egg is a directory created after the install, right?  So how is adding the foo.egg directory to sys.path any different than adding a regular directory created by an install?

Comment: @falsetru You are right open sudo with python, can you can import beautifulsoup, however, log in as normal user, it says Import Error: No module named BeautifulSoup4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tar.gz` is the source code of the library. You should unpack it, and you will find a `setup.py` script inside. Run:

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/share/pythonLib
```

This will create:

```
/share/pythonLib/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

In your scripts append that path to `sys.path` and everything should work fine.