# Install PyQt5.15.4 from tar.gz file

Tags: python, pyqt5, setup.py

I'm trying to install PyQt5.15.4 on a remote desktop that is not connected to internet (Anaconda distribution and PyCharm installed), hence I downloaded the tar.gz files from https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files and tried to use this solution : [Python import library from tar.gz?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173401/python-import-library-from-tar-gz) (it worked for other libraries I had to install such as python-docx). The problem is that there is no **setup.py** file. There is a **configure.py** file (I imagine it roughly do the same job), so I tried in cmd :

```
python configure.py install --prefix=<full path folder I used for other libraries I needed>
```

but I get:

```
Usage: python configure.py [opts] [name=value] [name+=value]
```

```
configure.py: error: no such option: --prefix
```

Do you have a tip ?

Comment: Why dont you use the wheel ?

Comment: I installed other libraries from tar.gz for the project so I wanted to try for PyQt as well. I finally found an other way but thanks for the idea !

Answer (score 0):

Download PyQT5 from here. https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pypi/packages/PyQt5/PyQt5-5.15.5.dev2108100905.tar.gz#md5=b39c03d821123c37715daffb0c1c3bb1

This will download tar.gz fie. open the terminal, CD through the relative path, paste the command here.

```
pip install PyQt5-5.15.5.dev2108100905.tar.gz
```

if you have your own tar.gz. Then use the name of that file, which will install automatically.

```
pip install yourfile.tar.gz
```

Please let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found an other way : I copied/pasted the PyQt5 files from updated Anaconda sites-packages on an other computer (connected to internet)  and it worked ! 
I'll try your solution if I encounter a problem.